# Difference between 幺 and 么

Tags: simplified-characters, character-variant

I saw words like 什幺 and 这幺 in the story I'm reading. I'm wondering if it's just a typo or do people actually spell it like that. If yes, what's the difference with 么?

Comment: Are you sure you parsed the sentence correctly? Do you have an example from the story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [漢典](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%B9%BA) and [國語辭典](https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=152806&la=0&powerMode=0) all say 幺 can be another form of [么](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B9%88)。

漢典：幺，小也。象子初生之形。俗字作么。
國語辭典：「么」的異體字。

However, both dictionaries also say 幺 have only one pronunciation ㄧㄠyao and it means small. Unlike 么, it isn't pronounced as ㄇㄛˊmó,˙ㄇㄚma, or ˙ㄇㄜme. So, it should not be used in 什幺 or 这幺.

Answer (score 1):

1.a. 维科汉英词典: 幺
adj.  (Trad=么, Pinyin=yao1) small
n.    (Trad=么, Pinyin=yao1) one on dice

(互动百科:本文章的内容选自, 并有 "互动在线" 授权许可)

1.b. 朗道汉英词典: 幺
one, youngest

2.维科汉英词典: 么
(Trad=么, Pinyin=me5) suffix of interrogative and relational pronouns